# Connecting to Oracle19C Server using Oracle11g client

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle19c, ora-01017

all

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle 19C database. I have installed two Oracle Clients (11g and 12c) because we need to support legacy programs. I can connect with no issue with any user using sqlplus through the 12c client. But if I use the 11g (11.2.0) client with any user. I always get:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Both clients have exactly the same sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files, so both clients point to the same database.

Any idea? Do I need to set some specific configuration in the 19c server? Or do I need to make some change in the 11g client? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the SQL Net protocol settings https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spmsu/check-for-sqlnet-allowed-logon-version-parameter-behavior.html#GUID-433E0DB9-026E-4322-A8FF-BA0E108AB28B

Comment: Don’t forget that making your database server compatible for 11g passwords is essentially rolling back security improvements that Oracle has put in place for you. If you do adjust the sql net parameters like Connor suggests, you should check that the users you need to login to have an 11g password hash stored in the database - dba_users has a password_versions column you should check out, if it doesn’t contain an old enough version then you’ll need to reset the password after changing the sqlnet parameter and connecting with a new session.

Comment: The sqlnet.ora file of my 19c instance in server side already has:

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11

And the dba_users columns contains:
SQL> select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users where username like 'user%';

USERNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ACCOUNT_STATUS                   PASSWORD_VERSIONS
user1
OPEN                             11G 12C

Comment: Your 11.2.0 client must be patched to at least 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4. Anything less is not compatible with 19c server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1)

[image]

- #9 - 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4 only. For Oracle Autonomous Transaction Processing and Oracle Autonomous Data Warehouse, there is additional limitation and 11.2.0.4 is the minimum supported client version.

Usually it is a bad idea to install more than one Oracle client (i.e. one each for 32-bit and 64-bit).

For some components, e.g. "Oracle OleDB Provider" it is even not possible to have more than just one version (again, one each for 32-bit and 64-bit) installed. This is a limitation of the old Windows COM architecture.

For other components it may work, however you need to set your `%PATH%` environment variable accordingly that it points to the correct folder where currently desired version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make a 11 client (ODP.Net + Instant Client 11.2) connect to a 19 DB, whatever changes I made to the sqlnet.ora file regarding security, etc. be it on the server or the client side. I always had a cryptic message about the impossibility to negociate protocols.

There was no problem when I installed Instant Client 19, except the fact that passwords are now case-sensitive. I can also use this new client with legacy databases running 11.2 software.

Answer (score 0):

I have connected to oracle 19C Release 19.0.0.0.0 using ODAC 11.2.0 without any issue. But if you want to connected to oracle 19C higher release you need to have ODAC 11.0.3 or higher. Still looking for way to connect using ODAC 11.0.2 to later Oracle 19C release.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add to sqlnet.ora

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT=11
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=11
```

Change the password in 11 client

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).