# Can we use System.Data.OracleClient in .Net against Oracle 19c?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, oracle19c, system.data.oracleclient

so we migrated Oracle 12.2 to 19c and the Asp.Net app that connects to oracle service is now failing with the following error:
Oracle 12560: TNS Protocol Adapter Error

before anything, I'd like to confirm that the .net dll System.Data.OracleClient would work against Oracle 19c or are we looking at migrating forcefully to ODP.Net??

Comment: Have you checked your connection string? That error is mainly associated with either connecting to a local instance (using oracle_sid and no connection string) when there is no local instance associated with that sid. It can also occur when you have a mismatch between your oracle_home and the driver used. Have you set the oracle_home environment variable? You may want to unset it (it's not usually used in Windows)

Comment: Oracle 19c *reads as* Oracle 12c Release 2 (12.2.0.3), so - basically - code you use *should work*. For more info, re-read what @Andrew said.

Answer (score 6):

It mainly depends on the client version, not the database version.

The `System.Data.OracleClient` namespace does not work anymore with Oracle client 18c or newer. If your application (i.e. the client) runs on your 19cdatabase server, then it will not work anymore.

NB, the `System.Data.OracleClient` driver is deprecated for more than 10 years.

Comment: So what is the alternate now. As if now I was am using this fall with Oracle 11g db but just the db got upgraded to 19c and connection started failing now

Comment: @ksrds Don't use `System.Data.OracleClient`, for alternatives see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Answer (score 2):

System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
So if you use ODP.NET v.12.X, this bunch of OracleClient and ODP.NET will work with Oracle 19c.
See also [Connecting to Oracle19C Server using Oracle11g client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64903256/connecting-to-oracle19c-server-using-oracle11g-client)