# Apache Airflow and Oracle Connection

Tags: oracle, airflow

I am trying to read data from a local oracle database (Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production).

I have created my own docker image:

```
# Use the base Apache Airflow image
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.3
# Set environment variables for the Oracle Instant Client
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
# Switch to the root user temporarily
USER root
# Install required packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    libaio1 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Create the Oracle directory with proper permissions
RUN mkdir -p $ORACLE_HOME && chown -R airflow: $ORACLE_HOME
# Create the tmp directory with proper permissions
RUN mkdir -p /tmp && chown -R airflow: /tmp
# Switch back to a non-root user (e.g., "airflow")
USER airflow
# Install Python packages required for Oracle client and Airflow Oracle provider
RUN pip install oracledb apache-airflow-providers-oracle pandas sqlalchemy
# Download and install the Oracle Instant Client
# https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html
COPY instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp/
COPY instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip -d $ORACLE_HOME && \
    unzip -o /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip -d $ORACLE_HOME 
# Delete ZIP Files
RUN rm -rf /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip
# Set environment variables for Oracle Instant Client
ENV PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME
ENV ORACLE_VERSION=19.22
```

In short: oracledb apache-airflow-providers-oracle pandas sqlalchemy as well as instantclient-basic-linux.x64-19.22.0.0.0dbru.zip from oracle.com was added to the standard image.

docker compose build works, docker compose init works, docker compose up works without errors.

Oracle shows up as connection type and I have created a connection:

[image]

My test DAG looks like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.providers.oracle.hooks.oracle import OracleHook

table_name = "DB.TABLE"
@task
def get_data_from_oracle():
    oracle_hook=OracleHook(oracle_conn_id='Oracle_***')
    data = oracle_hook.get_pandas_df(sql=f"SELECT COUNT(1) FROM {table_name}")
    return data.to_dict()

with DAG('oracle_test', start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1), schedule_interval='@once') as dag:
    data = get_data_from_oracle()
```

If I run said DAG I get errors which I can not resolve. It runs for around a minute and terminates with this errors: (I assume time out)

> [2024-03-21T10:27:31.754+0000] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 8 for task get_data_from_oracle (DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=P26GiMCTIFWWPDhhkB4vZQ==).
> DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
> [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
> Help: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#dpy-4011; 534)

Or, depending on configuration: (no time out)

> [2024-03-21, 16:57:08 CET] {standard_task_runner.py:107} ERROR - Failed to execute job 16 for task get_data_from_oracle (DPY-6005: cannot connect to database (CONNECTION_ID=Ma2uz0YYUUhkdOMBsNNS0w==).
> DPY-6003: SID "***" is not registered with the listener at host "10.*.*.*" port 1524. (Similar to ORA-12505); 5827)

I double checked ip, ping, SID (via Query) and so on.

I assume I do something horribly wrong in either

1. The setup of the container
2. The DAG
3. The connection to Oracle (which is really unclear in
   documentation)

Either way internet research lead to no solution. If anyone can provide me with tips or a working way to connect to an Oracle DB I'd be grateful. Please don't make me go back to SSIS.

**Update:** The same query towards a DB with *Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production* works without any problems. It seems to be an issue with version / drivers.

Comment: From the error message, it looks like you're trying to connect to Oracle on port 1524. Are you 100% sure this is correct ? Usually, Oracle runs on port 1521.

Comment: Yes - I double and tripple checked. I can connect on said port via DBeaver (and interact with the database) as well as TNSPING the name and get port 1524 as an answer. I have no explanation on why this port was shifted... maybe multiple instances / services on one linux host require different ports? Will try 1521 real quick just to rule this out tough.

Comment: Interesting: If I change the Port the error changes: 
right port: No SID registered at port...
wrong port: Cannot connect to DB. So I Assume the DB somehow responds or at least gets reached by airflow

Comment: According to https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#error-messages, one possible reason for DPY-4011 is that the DB enforces Native Network Encryption (NNE) which is not supported in Thin Mode. Could you run the query `SELECT network_service_banner FROM v$session_connect_info;` on your Oracle DB to check whether NNE is enabled?

Comment: Also, have you tried connecting to Oracle from a standalone Python script running locally (as described in https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html ) ? In theory, there could be a version problem because the server version 11.2.0.4 is really old, although the Oracle docs suggest connecting to 11.2.0.4 with a 19c client should work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64908713/610979 )

Comment: I am not sure on how to connect this table to "my" connection attempt:

> SELECT DISTINCT OSUSER FROM v$session_connect_info
TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Oracle Advanced Security: crypto-checksumming service for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Oracle Advanced Security: encryption service for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

(mind the distinct)

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production <- This Version seems to work?! So it looks like a problem with the version of the DB?! Will test further.